# Create a view with a unique key from a tables without a primary key

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, view, primary-key

I have few oracle tables without primary keys.I cannot modify this database design,since it is used by several applications. Adding an Auto increment field is also not an option.

In order **to generate Edmx in Entity Framework I need a unique field** in the table.
So what I'm trying to do is creating a view with an unique key.

My table is like :

```
 CREATE TABLE "ENTITLEMENTS"
(   
    "TOKEN" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR), 
    "ENROLLED_FUNCTION" VARCHAR2(9 CHAR)
);
```

Is there a way to show an auto generated identity field from a view. If so how?

Comment: You can create a view with unique key or primary key (Initially disabled)

Comment: Can I do it even if I don't have a primary key on the table?
If so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

`Select row_number() OVER (ORDER BY TOKEN,ENROLLED_FUNCTION ),TOKEN,ENROLLED_FUNCTION  From ENTITLEMENTS`

Answer (score 2):

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm) and [also this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm#i2065510)

For example

```
CREATE TABLE DATASET ( VAL1 CHAR ( 1 CHAR ),
                   VAL2 VARCHAR2 ( 10 CHAR ),
                   VAL3 NUMBER );

INSERT INTO
      DATASET ( VAL1,
              VAL2,
              VAL3 )
VALUES
      ( 'b',
        'b-details',
        2 );

INSERT INTO
      DATASET ( VAL1,
              VAL2,
              VAL3 )
VALUES
      ( 'a',
        'a-details',
        1 );

INSERT INTO
      DATASET ( VAL1,
              VAL2,
              VAL3 )
VALUES
      ( 'c',
        'c-details',
        3 );

INSERT INTO
      DATASET ( VAL1,
              VAL2,
              VAL3 )
VALUES
      ( 'a',
        'dup',
        4 );

INSERT INTO
      DATASET ( VAL1,
              VAL2,
              VAL3 )
VALUES
      ( 'c',
        'c-details',
        5 );

COMMIT;


CREATE VIEW TESTER ( C1,
                 C2,
                 C3  UNIQUE RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE )
AS
    SELECT
          VAL1,
          VAL2,
          VAL3
    FROM
          DATASET;
```